# unknown problem in siunitx

Tags: xetex, siunitx

I'm trying to use the inch mark (the double prime) in a piece of text; in the past I've gotten away with

```
4 $''$ \times 6 $''$
```

but for some reason that doesn't work when that line is an item in an itemized list. I'm now experimenting with the siunitx package, but now there's a new problem. This MOLMWE (More or Less Minimal Working Example)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\setromanfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}

\sisetup{detect-all = true}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = {}]{\inchQ}{\prime\prime}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item \SI{4 \times 6}{\inchQ} index cards

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

produces an incorrect result; I'd attach an image, but I don't have sufficient reputation for that privilege. What's the problem, if you can spot it from just the code, and how do I fix it?

P.S. As for the MOLMWE: I included possibly extraneous material because I wasn't sure whether it was relevant and decided to play it safe.

Comment: `siunitx` already defines the unit `\arcsecond` (and `\arcminute`).

Comment: The error is `"invalid-token-in-number"`, caused by `\times`.

Comment: Does that mean I shouldn't be using \times in text? And if so, is there a better way to incorporate that symbol?

Comment: @user35810 `siunitx` converts `x` in the input as an product (see the options `input-product` and `output-product`).

Comment: What's wrong with just doing `$4''\times6''$`?  If you want to use the text font instead of the maths font, then just try `$\rm 4''\times6''$`.

Answer (score 4):

I’d use the UTF characters here and not the `\prime\prime` (better would be `siunitx`’ default setting `{}^{\prime\prime}` which is `''`, anyway). That way, the glyphs are taken from the same font as the digits.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\setromanfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\sisetup{
  detect-all = true,
  text-arcsecond=″,
  text-arcminute=′,
  math-arcsecond=″,
  math-arcminute=′,
}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product={}]\inchQ{\SIUnitSymbolArcsecond}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product={}]\footQ{\SIUnitSymbolArcminute}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Arcseconds
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \SI{4 x 6}{\arcsecond}
    \item $\SI{4 x 6}{\arcsecond}$
  \end{itemize}
  \item Inches
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \SI{4 x 6}{\inchQ}
    \item $\SI{4 x 6}{\inchQ}$
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Extra marks for maintaining the semantic difference between an arc and inches :-)